# Django custom ChoiceField form with selected=selected

Tags: html, django, forms, choicefield

I have the following form:

```
POSSIBLE_POSITIONS = (
    ('1', 'Brazo'),
    ('2', 'Muñeca'),
    ('3', 'Pierna'),
    ('4', 'Pie'),
)

class PositionForm(forms.Form):
    position = forms.ChoiceField(choices = POSSIBLE_POSITIONS, label="", initial=1, widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))
```

Here is the model that uses that positions:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=POSSIBLE_POSITIONS, default=1)
```

And this is the view:

```
def modify(request):
    return render(request, 'interface/modify.html', {'user': User.objects.get(pk=id), 'device_list': Device.objects.all(), 'form': PositionForm()})
```

I would like to know, how to select the default `Position` based on the current `user.position`.

Just like I do here:

```
<select name="device_id" class="form-control">
   {% for device in device_list %}
      {% if device.id == user.device.id %}
         <option selected="selected">{{ device.id }}</option>
      {% else %}
         <option>{{ device.id }}</option>
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% if user.device.id == None %}
      <option selected="selected"> Sin dispositivo </option>
   {% else %}
      <option> Sin dispositivo </option>
   {% endif %}
</select>
```

But I don't know how to do it here:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Posición actual dispositivo</label>
   {{ form }}
</div>
```

Comment: if i understood you correctly you just need to do the following <option {% if user.position %} selected {% endif %}>

Comment: Position can be 1,2,3,4. I need to check what is the current position of that user, and make the form that is equals to user.position the selected one. Can you show me the code? I don't get that snipet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you should do the following modification in your view:

```
def modify(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = PositionForm(initial={'position': user.position})
    return render(request, 'interface/modify.html', {'user': user, 'device_list': Device.objects.all(), 'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select any option by manually doing that in regular html like that

```html
<select name="device_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="1"> Brazo</option>
            <option value="2"> Muñeca</option>
            <option value="3" selected> Pierna</option>
            <option value="4"> Pie </option>
            
</select>
```

so you can just add this if statment in your option tag

```
`<option {% if user.position %} selected {% endif %}>`
```

and the selected one will be the default one

Comment: I need to add that form on multiple places. Also this has to be an atrribute of a model. If I set manually I have to change the possibilities manually from all places.